# Java loop gets terminated without any error

Tags: java, arraylist, comparator

I have a main program which makes uses of two player objects and compares their result. It executes 10000 matches in a loop.

```
while(i<10000){
            game.compare(a, b);
            i++;
        }
```

Now this loop internally calls another class which has code to play 1000 games between two objects. And it prints me who has more games in one match.

That means intotal I should be getting results 10000 times but I see my program executes and displays results for some 10 matches and then it terminates without any error.

Could anyone has any suggestions like where am going wrong??

Thanks.

Comment: May be that method modifying *i* ?

Comment: In `game.compare`?  You're going to have to post a [mcve] if you want any hope of help.

Comment: What is the value of `i` each time the loop executes?

Comment: What is `i`'s starting value?  Note: If you want to loop a fixed number of times, consider using a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

As the same value of i was used in my subclass as well; the program was getting terminated after "i" number of iterations without any error.

Here is my complete implementation code:
https://github.com/kakarrot007/RockPaperScissors/tree/master

The main program iterates for 3 times and for each iteration it compares two players for 10 games and prints the total number of wins for each player.
So you will be able to see 3*10 = 30 times the matches are played.